# Pandas: how to assign time interval groupby key back to the original dataframe

Tags: pandas, time-series

suppose I have a time series dataframe

```
              x
01-01 5:00    10
01-02 7:00    12
01-03 9:00    15
01-04 6:00    9
01-05 3:00    11
01-06 8:00    17
```

and I group them by, say every 3 days. I can use either `resample` or `groupby` over the time grouper to group them, I have no problem on that. However, I do not see a straightforward way to assign the group key back to the original dataframe, this information is very helpful for my case. For example, I would like to see a new column called "grouper" like this.

```
              x    grouper
01-01 5:00    10   01-03
01-02 7:00    12   01-03
01-03 9:00    15   01-03
01-04 6:00    9    01-06
01-05 3:00    11   01-06
01-06 8:00    17   01-06
```

Any idea?

Comment: kindly share your code

Comment: What does your grouper dataframe look like?

Answer (score 1):

Work with the `grouper` object, that way you can map the group labels back to the DataFrame. Since `datetimes` require a year I'll create a new series not to ruin the DataFrame's index and then `strftime` the group labels to remove the year (it defaults to 1900).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [10,12,15,9,11,17]},
                  index=['01-01 5:00', '01-02 7:00', '01-03 9:00', '01-04 6:00',
                         '01-05 3:00', '01-06 8:00'])
```

---

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m-%d %H:%M').to_frame()

gp = s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='3D', label='left')).grouper

df['grouper'] = (pd.Series(gp.codes_info, index=df.index)
                    .map(dict(zip(gp.codes[0], gp.levels[0])))
                    .dt.strftime('%m-%d'))
```

---

```
             x grouper
01-01 5:00  10   01-01
01-02 7:00  12   01-01
01-03 9:00  15   01-01
01-04 6:00   9   01-04
01-05 3:00  11   01-04
01-06 8:00  17   01-04
```

Comment: wow, you saved my day! Not knew this grouper trick.